# Residue calculus

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, infinity

How to solve the following integrand: 
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx\;?$$
I know how to evaluate it by using the path of a rectangle, but it is too difficult and would make some mistakes.

I am wondering if there is a simpler way to solve questions like this. Thanks！

Comment: This is one of the standard integrals you learn to do in a complex variables class. You have to use the function $e^{iz}/z$ and do a contour in the upper half plane. Yes, you do need to do a little semicircle around the origin because there is a pole there (and you will pick up half the residue). Just practice doing problems like this. That's what homework is for. (I would use a semicircular path, not a rectangular path. But you do need some analysis to see why the integral around the large semicircle goes to 0 in the limit.)

Comment: Okay. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This integral is known as the [Dirichlet Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral) (or at least it almost is), and there are several ways to solve it that vary in dificulty depending on what techniques you know, though contour integration is one of the simpler ones.